# Сгруппировать данные по Like % значениям

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть 2 таблицы

**MAs:**

- id
- user_id
- description_id
- count
- date

  **MADescriptions**
- id
- action

  Мне надо посчитать кол-во людей(user_id) и сумму(count)  за определенный период (date), сгруппировав
  по действиям (action)

  действий много

  spent_1
  spent_2
  ...
  spent_n

  got_1
  got_2
  ...
  got_n

  buy_1
  buy_2
  ...
  buy_n

  Этот запрос мне по отдельности считает сначала spent,потом got,затем buy
  Все правильно делает,но как это сделать в одном запросе?

  ```
  SELECT MAs.date   , 
    count(DISTINCT (MAs.user_id)) AS users,
    sum(MAs.count) AS sum

  FROM
    MAs
  JOIN
    MADescriptions
  ON
  MAs.description_id = MADescriptions.id
  WHERE
    MAs.date BETWEEN '2018-10-08' AND '2018-10-15'
    AND MADescriptions.action LIKE 'spent%'; //тут меня на 'got%' 'buy%'
  ```

Пытался что то типа такого сделать, оно считает,но ответы разные, если сравнивать с ответами полученными их запроса выше

```
SELECT MAs.date
     , count(DISTINCT (MAs.user_id)) AS users

     , sum(MADescriptions.action LIKE 'spent%') AS spent
     , sum(MADescriptions.action LIKE 'got%') AS got
     , sum(MADescriptions.action LIKE 'bought%') AS bought

FROM
  MAs
JOIN
  MADescriptions
ON
MAs.description_id = MADescriptions.id
WHERE
  MAs.date BETWEEN '2018-10-08' AND '2018-10-15'
  Group by  MAs.date
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно, я думаю, использовать `CASE`

```
GROUP BY
CASE
    MADescriptions.action type LIKE 'spent%' THEN 'spent'
    MADescriptions.action type LIKE 'got%' THEN 'got'
    MADescriptions.action type LIKE 'buy%' THEN 'buy'
    ELSE NULL
END
```